# Como funciona exatamente o algoritmo SHA-256

Tags: criptografia, hash, sha-256

Eu dei uma procurada na internet, mas os resultados sobre o funcionamento do algoritmo `SHA-256` não me satisfizeram, se alguem puder me auxiliar eu ficarei grato.

Vlw.

Comment: Com certeza, o que você ta procurando ta nesse link em inglês, mas to sem tempo de traduzir pra virar uma verdadeira resposta.  http://www.iwar.org.uk/comsec/resources/cipher/sha256-384-512.pdf

Comment: O que você procura para ler satisfazer?