# Como criar um sistema para gerar hashes e conseguir quebrar sem a string original?

Tags: criptografia

Existe alguma forma de quebrar o Sha-256? Existe um processo matemático para conseguir quebrar?

Preciso criar um programa que gera vários hashes e outro para quebrar sem ter a string original (Similar ao Bitcoin), apenas usando o processamento.

Comment: Não dá. Esses hashes criptográficos são feitos justamente pra ser muito difícil adivinhar a entrada.

Comment: Mas como o sistema de mineração do bitcoin consegue quebrar?

Comment: Eu sei que o algoritmo resolve quebra-cabeças matemáticos, mas não entendo como é o processo.

Comment: O sistema do bitcoin não quebra. Ele estabelece um limite para o que é um hash "aceitável" (ex.: 10 zeros à esquerda) e qualquer hash que satisfaça essa condição é aceito no *blockchain*. Se um valor *exato* fosse necessário, nem todos os mineradores do mundo conseguiriam quebrar um único hash...

Comment: Relacionado: ["Como funciona exatamente o algoritmo SHA-256"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/97566/215)

Answer (score 9):

O SHA-256, como qualquer sistema de hash bem feito, é **resistente a pré-imagem** (["função de mão única"](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_m%C3%A3o_%C3%BAnica)). Isso significa que, dado o valor de um hash, é impraticável se descobrir (com alta probabilidade) algum dado que dê origem àquele hash. Assim, a única maneira conhecida de se "inverter o hash" é gerando uma grande quantidade de dados e hasheando-os um a um, até chegar no mesmo resultado do hash original.

Como o SHA-256 é um hash bastante rápido - e facilmente paralelizável - é possível quebrar muitos hashes caso o dado original seja uma string razoavelmente curta (ex.: senhas típicas de usuários). Por essa razão ele é frequentemente usado em conjunto com um **sal**, que é um valor aleatório que é concatenado ao dado antes do mesmo ser hasheado, e então salvo junto com o valor do hash. Se esse sal for suficientemente longo (hoje em dia usa-se 64 bits, creio eu, mas para garantir é melhor 128 ou mais) então <del>é totalmente impraticável inverter o hash - pois o número de tentativas necessárias pra acertar é superior ao poder computacional combinado de toda a humanidade</del>.

(Falei bobagem: a dificuldade para inverter **um** hash é a mesma, usando sal ou não; o sal evita somente que você quebre **muitos** hashes usando um único processamento. [Não use SHA-256 para proteger senhas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/215), ou qualquer outro dado de **baixa entropia**. A menos que você consiga manter o sal secreto, é claro, mas aí ele é chamado de "chave" e a construção resultante é uma forma de [MAC](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autenticador_de_mensagem).)

Nota: você menciona o Bitcoin, mas o sistema de mineração do Bitcoin *não inverte hashes* em nenhuma parte de sua operação. O que é feito é pegar o hash do bloco que está sendo formado (inclui o hash de todo o *blockchain* atrás dele, numa estrutura conhecida como [*Merkle Tree*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rvores_de_Merkle)) e anexar um valor aleatório, hasheando e vendo se o resultado satisfaz a ao critério de dificuldade da rede. Esse critério é basicamente verificar se o valor final é menor ou igual a um valor arbitrário, que é ajustado pra cima ou pra baixo dependendo do poder de processamento combinado de toda a rede Bitcoin (estimado conforme a frequência com que novos blocos são criados, em comparação com o alvo de 1 bloco a cada 10 minutos).